# In C# 7, How Can I Make a New ValueTuple from an Existing and New Elements?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, valuetuple

In C# 7 we have value tuples of the form `(a, b, c, ...)` and deconstruction of them (via `var (a, b, c, ...) = (a, b, c, ...)`).

I have a tuple of the form `(row: <int>, column: <int>)`, and I want to create a **new tuple** of the form `(row: <int>, column: <int>, content: <char>)` using the previous one.

In Python I can do:

```py
existing = [1, 2]
new = [*existing, 3]
```

Or with dicts:

```py
existing = {'row':1, 'column':2}
new = {**existing, 'content':'1'}
```

Is there a similar pattern in C#?

I can of course deconstruct the tuple into variables, then recombine them:

```
var (row, column) = (row: 1, column: 2);
var result = (row, column, content: '1');
```

However the actual situation is more complex. I have a *function* that returns the existing tuple, and an one-line function that constructs the new. If I simplify this it will be like:

```
private (int row, int column) ExistingTuple() => (row: 1, column: 2);

private (int row, int column, char content) NewTuple() => (/* What should I do here */ExistingTuple(), content: '1');
```

For the simplicity and the readability, I want it as an arrow function (`T F() => E;`). If I would implement my suggestion, it will be seem like:

```
private (int row, int column, char content) NewTuple()
{
    var (row, column) = ExistingTuple();
    return (row, column, content: '1');
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: I don't believe that this is achievable currently (although I'm not certain of this).

Comment: or change to Python! ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can write it as an extension method, though it sounds like maybe that's not as concise as you'd like:

```cs
public static (T1, T2, T3) TupleAppend<T1, T2, T3>(
   this (T1, T2) me,
   T3 value
) =>
   (me.Item1, me.Item2, value);
```

Used as:

```
var triple = (1, 2).TupleAppend(3);
```

You'd also need an overload for every size, and even more overloads if you wanted to add more than one new item at once.

Comment: If this is the only way I prefer to use my way. It's more readable, and less code to write.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman As long as you put the extension methods in a library, and in a place by themselves so they aren't cluttering anything, you should just have to write them once. The actual appending operation is a lot clearer like this, compared to manual destructuring/restructuring. You can also use a shorter name than `TupleAppend` as well. (Could even be really short, like `a` or something, and then it's almost like an operator.)

Answer (score 1):

From a design perspective, these are probably two different data types. The `(row, col)` tuples are indexes for the actual data. You can therefore use nested tuples to express this intent:

```
private ((int row, int column), char content) EnrichedTuple() => 
    (ExistingTuple(), content: '1');
```